# How to get time difference between 2 times which are in 24 hours format in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I want to calculate time difference between two times which are in 24hours format.
Suppose start time is 23.00 PM and endtime is 2.00 AM. Then it should show 3 hours.

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Comment: Angular has little to do with time manipulation. [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/), on the other hand, does

Comment: I'd also recommend Moment for every kind of time manipulation. But if you don't want to add another library, you could probably use the `Date` object to parse the strings (depends a bit on the strings) then take the difference in timestamps and treat this difference as an UTC timestamp to get the correct days/hours/minutes/...

Comment: do you just want the difference in hours or minutes and seconds too

Answer (score -1):

To compare dates, the best way is to use the date in milliseconds with the function `getTime()`.

```
const diffInMilliseconds = endTime.getTime() - starTime.getTime() // 10800000
const diffInHours = diffInMilliseconds / 3600000 // 3 hours
```